# how to prove the following fact in sheaf cohomology ?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables

Let $X$ be a compact complex n-fold . Then for every coherent sheaf $\mathfrak{F}$ on $X$ , and every holomorphic line bundle $L$ on $X$ , then the dimension of $H^0 (X,\mathfrak{F}\otimes\mathcal{O}_X(L))$ does not depend on $L$ when dim Supp$\mathfrak{F}=0$ .

Comment: Context? Motivation? Some comments to illustrate which cases you can already do, what you know, etc?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\dim\mathrm{Supp}\\, \mathfrak F=0$ implies that $\mathfrak F\otimes \mathscr O_X(L)\simeq \mathfrak F$ and hence its cohomology is independent of $L$.

Comment: how to get this isomorphism ? 

Comment: The support of $\mathfrak{F}$ is just a finite set of closed points. Now choose trivializations of $L$ around each point to get the desired isomorphism.